# Socket Buffer setting for JBoss 7

Tags: sockets, jboss, jboss7.x

In JBoss 5.1, there used to be a setting called **socketBuffer** which we could configure in the server.xml inside jbossweb.sar i.e. jbossweb.sar\server.xml, it looked something like this.

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" socketBuffer="64000"/>
```

Does someone have any idea what the corresponding setting in JBoss 7 is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there is no such parameter. I don't find any information about it but how I see it:

- connector is defined in `standolne.xml` file in that fragment:

  ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
      <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
      <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
          <alias name="localhost"/>
          <alias name="example.com"/>
      </virtual-server>
  </subsystem>
  ```
- there is XSD file which describe these part of configuration (it can be found in `docs` directory): `jboss-as-web_1_1.xsd`
- there is no information about `socketBuffer` parameter
- in other XSD files I also don't fine such parameter
- and in jboss-cli I also don't see any such parameter (or similar)

Of course I can be wrong and just cannot find it.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, I checked those files and asked this question here since I couldn't find a relevant setting. If there is no such setting, it would basically mean that my app would perform about 10 times slower than it did with JBoss 5 under WAN conditions (200 ms round trip latency)

Comment: I looked all over the place and found nothing short of a code change in a bunch of files in JBoss 7.2 to make this option configurable. I feel it's a gross oversight on part of JBoss to have missed this.